# Frequency join statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

`users`:

```
id | name
-----------
 1 | user 1
 2 | user 2
 3 | user 3
```

and `posts`:

```
id | userId | text
--------------------
 1 |      1 | text 1
 2 |      1 | text 2
 3 |      2 | text 3
 4 |      2 | text 4
 5 |      2 | text 5
 6 |      2 | text 6
```

I need to retrieve `users` ordered by post-frequency, e.g.:

```
id | name   | posts
-------------------
 2 | user 2 |     4
 1 | user 1 |     1
 3 | user 3 |     0
```

Some users might not have posts!

Currently I have 2 queries and doing it in 3 steps:

1. retrieve all users
2. retrieve all posts grouped by `userId`
3. use `php` to join the above

**Question**

Is the above possible to do in a single sql query?

Comment: `select u.id, u.name, count(p.id) as posts from users u left outer join posts p on u.id = p.userId group by u.id, u.name order by posts desc`  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36eb4/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version, which prevents listing all fields from `users` table in group by clause. Also more fast in many cases IMO.

```
select u.id, u.name, coalesce(c.cnt, 0) as posts
from users u
left join 
  (select userId, couint(*) cnt from posts group by userId) c
on u.id = c.userId
```

Comment: This is amazing! I didn't know `coalesce` function!

Answer (score 3):

```
select u.id, u.name, count(p.id) as posts
from users u
left join posts p on p.userid = u.id
group by u.id, u.name
order by posts desc
```

Comment: Thank you. That works great, although Hamlet's solution gives me more flexibility.